# Why we can not construct a Binary Search Tree from an unsorted array in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm

Even if Space complexity does not matter, why is this impossible? 
Is there a way out?
All I can come up with is O(nlogn) time as Average and O(n^2) as Worst case.

Comment: How are you getting O(n^2) worst case? Merge sort is O(nlogn).

Comment: @Adam: The question is about BSTs.

Comment: @Adam: naively? I would use that adverb for the process which just traverses the array and adds each element. That's a horrible idea here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can traverse the tree in O(n).

If you could build a tree in O(n), you would have a sorting algorithm which is also O(n).

But that's impossible - comparison sort cannot be done less than [O(nlogn)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Performance_limits_and_advantages_of_different_sorting_techniques).

---

Note: if you use a *balanced* binary tree, you can construct it in O(nlogn).

Comment: Great answer. Except for radix sort of course, but I guess that doesn't count ;)

Comment: I probably should have said "comparison sort" ;)

Comment: Not only radix: you can have linear counting sort, bucket sort and many variations (if sorted keys are somehow constrained, of course)